# Django - CreateView fails, am redirected to empty create view

Tags: python, django

My CreateView seems to be failing but I am unsure as to why. I am being redirected to an empty CreateView with no errors or messages to tell me why its failing.

I would of thought I would of been redirected to CreateView with the entered Data saved and an error. I've checked admin for the model and the record is not being created.

the issue seems to be server side but I am not getting any output in console I just get 200s

```
"POST /sites/site/add_subnet/7 HTTP/1.1" 200 41406
```

my forms.py:

```
class AddSubnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteSubnets
        fields = ['device_data','subnet', 'subnet_type', 'circuit', 'vlan_id', 'peer_desc']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        site_id = kwargs.pop('site_id', None)
        super(AddSubnetForm, self).__init__(*args)
        self.fields['circuit'].queryset = Circuits.objects.filter(site_data=site_id)
```

view.py:

```
class AddSubnet(CreateView):
    form_class = AddSubnetForm
    template_name = "sites/edit_subnet.html"

@method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.add_subnet')))
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
    self.site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.site_id) 
    return super(AddSubnet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        return reverse_lazy("sites:site_detail_subnets", args=(self.site_id,))

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.site_data = self.site
    return super(AddSubnet, self).form_valid(form)

def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['site_id'] = self.site_id
    return kwargs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['SiteID']=self.site_id
    context['SiteName']=self.site.location
    context['FormType']='Add'
    context['active_subnets']='class="active"'

    return context
```

template:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="col-lg-3">
    {{ result }}
    {{ form.errors }}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            alert(message);
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden_field }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ field.label_tag }}

            {% if form.is_bound %}
            {% if field.errors %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ error }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
            {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if field.help_text %}
            <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="{{ FormType }} Subnet" class="btn btn-primary" />
            {% if FormType != 'Add' %}
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'sites:site_overview' SiteID %}">Delete</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>      
    </form>
</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation - as is, your view's class is only defined by the first two lines and everything else is interpreted as stand alone functions, not methods of the class.

Comment: Also when instanciating the form you want to pass the kwags to the `super` call, ie in `AddSubnetForm.__init__` replace `super(AddSubnetForm, self).__init__(*args)` with `super(AddSubnetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not calling `super` in your `get_form_kwargs` method, so the POSTed data is not actually being passed to the form. You probably need:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['site_id'] = self.site_id
    return kwargs
```

Comment: thanks for your assistance, however the same is still happening, I git add and get taken back to a blank form, is there anything I can print to console within the class definitions that could help?

Comment: As Bruno suggests, you need to pass `**kwargs` to the super call in the form init.